# How do I get this simple working program to run with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, notepad++

I wrote a JS program that's just a D20 that also spits out a funny message based on what number you roll (code below). I got it working in the chrome browser tools, and I wanted to try getting it to be easier to run over and over during a dnd session. I have it saved in Notepad++, I got the plugin NPPExec and I got node.js, got everything installed, and then paired my Notepad++ console with node.js to have node.js without switching window to copy paste code (note: I literally just followed online directions word for word for this and it worked, I didn't figure out how to do this on my own).

However, when I try to run my program in the node.js console (using: >node xxx.js or >node [file location]) or the in-notepad++ console (using the instructions from the internet) I get these 2 weird errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: node is not defined
```

(from the node.js console)

and

```
; about to start a child process: "npm.cmd start"
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

(from the node.js-linked console embedded in Notepad++)

Everything is saved together as the internet said to do, and I know the file exists cause I can see it as I'm trying to run it.

Now I'll drop some code here, not sure what's important or needed but I'll include what the internet told me to use as commands and then the .js I wrote in case I need to add or change something there to make it work with node.js

RunNPM command:

```
cd "$CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
npm.cmd start
```

RunNodejs command:

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
node $(FILE_NAME)
```

And the funny D20 (which I know works! :) I was so excited):

```
let roll = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20);
let tidbit = roll;
console.log(roll);
switch (tidbit) {
    case 1:
        console.log('Oof.');
        break;
    case 2:
        console.log('At least it\'s not  a one!');
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log('They say it\'s lucky, but I don\'t know about that.');
        break;
    case 4:
        console.log('WeirdChamp');
        break;
    case 5:
        console.log('Sadge');
        break;
    case 6:
        console.log('Better hope you have a good modifier!');
        break;
    case 7:
        console.log('ludwig7 in the chat boys');
        break;
    case 8:
        console.log('The future is muddy sometimes.');
        break;
    case 9:
        console.log('Almost halfway to a nat20! Almost.');
        break;
    case 10:
        console.log('Hey DM, can I multiply by 2?');
        break;
    case 11:
        console.log('Make a wish if the time includes an 11.');
        break;
    case 12:
        console.log('You\'re not a baker.');
        break;
    case 13:
        console.log('Is it lucky or unlucky? I\'ve heard it both ways.');
        break;
    case 14:
        console.log('What a dumb number, literally what do I put here?');
        break;
    case 15:
        console.log('Nice cock.');
        break;
    case 16:
        console.log('Your roll can drive! Buy it a car.');
        break;
    case 17:
        console.log('So many songs are named this, why?');
        break;
    case 18:
        console.log('Your roll should go buy a lottery ticket.');
        break;
    case 19:
        console.log('So close to perfect!');
        break;
    case 20:
        console.log('poggers');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Oops! Lillie messed up');
}
```

ANSWERED: Using the pathing method from Amith's comment and the `cd /d` command prompt function from Cigien the program now runs in windows command prompt! Coolest D20 ever. Thank you!!!

EDIT 2: and after restarting notepad++ it now lets me run it embedded there! coding is crack :)

Comment: NodeJS may not be installed or not available on the environment variables (on windows) or not available in path (on unix/linux).

Comment: @Amith Thanks! I am on windows. So from a simple google search, it looks like environment variables are just anything that helps programs run if I have that right? Which ones do I need to get/change/mess with to make this work? Everything installed fine, and beyond that my understanding is limited, I just wanted my code to run pretty lol. Thanks again though!

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-PATH-Environment-Variable-on-Windows

. This is an easy guide to follow, you would need to add nodejs to path by specifying where you installed nodejs. Then you could access nodejs from any terminal / console.

Comment: ok, using the guide I pathed the node install location to be the same folder as my .js file, still getting the same problems so I think I may have messed up the node.js install at some point

Comment: The `PATH` entry should point to the location where `node.exe` can be found, not where your `.js` file is.  Think of `PATH` as the answer to "if I have to run a program by name, that could be anywhere on my system, where should I attempt to find it?"  (In this case, "program" means Node and not your own program, which is technically just an "input" to the Node program at this point.)

Comment: I GOT IT TO RUN IN WINDOWS CMD!!! I used your guide to path node.exe to the same folder as my program then used the cmdprompt code from the guy below to run the command in the folder and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome and congratulations on your first programming milestone!

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: node is not defined
> ```

This error suggests that you might be attempting to run Node from within Node.

> ```
> ; about to start a child process: "npm.cmd start"
> CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

It seems that possibly Node didn't put itself on your [system `PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), or (possibly?) your Notepad++ has been running since before you installed Node.  If it's not that, then maybe you haven't written a `package.json` file in the same location, which is something `npm start` would expect to see to know what to actually start.

You might have better luck running your `node xxx.js` command in the place where you tried your `npm start` command.

Alternatively you could bypass Notepad++ altogether and do it directly in a Command Prompt window:

```
cd /d "{the folder where xxx.js is created}"
node xxx.js
```

If that still fails, then your next likely step would be to investigate how to get Node added to your system `PATH`.  The simplest way to do that might be to uninstall and reinstall Node, ensuring that "Add to PATH" is enabled during setup:

[image: Node installation screen showing "Add to PATH" option]

Rebooting after the reinstallation will ensure that every program can "see" that Node has been added to the `PATH`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I first tried running ```node xxx.js``` in the other console as you recommended, no dice (lol). I then tried using windows cmd, using that ```cd /d "{folder}" ``` and got the error ```  'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ``` . I think my next step is uninstall and reinstall node.js, then invesitage the system ```PATH``` . tysm!

Comment: Great idea.  I've edited my answer to reflect this, pointing out that the Node installer will itself add Node to the `PATH` if the correct option is selected.  Rebooting after installation is the easiest way to ensure that the addition to the `PATH` is seen by everything.

Comment: OHMYGOD OHMYGOD OHMYGOD I GOT IT TO RUN IN WINDOWS CMD!!! I used the guide from the comment above then used your ``` cd/d "folder" ``` then ``` node xxx.js ``` and it printed "4 weirdchamp" and I jumped up yelling and scared the cat.

Comment: Congratulations (and condolences to the cat).  The Command Prompt will likely prove quite useful as you continue to develop, but I suspect that with your `PATH` issue sorted, you should now also be able to run it from within Notepad++ as originally desired.

Comment: and boom. runs in notepad. :) im officially hooked on coding